# How to use edit existing docx. document using patches from 'docx' package in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, buffer, docx

I am working on POC where I have to replace some values in the existing docx file. I am using docx (https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx) package. Where they have provided the functionality of patches (https://docx.js.org/#/usage/patcher).

Now when I create a fresh document using same package it is straight forward approach in reactjs but when it comes to edit/replace existing document values I was not able to find any solid example for Reactjs.

In below code, as fs module not available in client side, I have created a api where it returns a buffer data, and I am just passing it to patchDocument({}) method.

```
  const myPatcher = (a) => {
    patchDocument({
        outputType: 'nodebuffer',
        data: a.data,
        patches: {
            name: {
                type: PatchType.PARAGRAPH,
                children: [new TextRun('TEST')],
            },
        },
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        fetch('http://localhost:8000/hello_world')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                myPatcher(data.data);
            });
    }
    fetchData();
}, []);
```

I am not very sure is this the correct approach or not because I am using this for very first time. So if anyone could help me OR provide me any react snipette where I can easily modify exising docx file and download it at the client / UI side

Below is the data I am trying to replace {{name}}.

I have used another package docxtemplater and able to achieve the results, but some modules are paid so I can not use it

[image]